# A doubt about a naive generalization of inner product in elementary quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, metric-tensor, quantum-states

A elementary study of Quantum Mechanics, following $[1]$, yields in the realization that the basic algebraic structure are the complex vector spaces $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Then a contravariant vector (using the terminology of Differential Geometry/General Relativity) is simply defined as an element of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ ;

> $$\mid x \rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \tag{1}$$

In $(1)$, these vectors are called *Ket*.

Futhermore, concerning the vector space $\mathcal{L}(V,U)$ there's a particular subspace called Dual vector space $\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{K}) \equiv V^{*}$ which is the Vector Space of the Covariant Vectors (Linear Functionals). So, for the quantum mechanics, you can define:

> $$\begin{array}{rl}
> \langle y \mid:\mathbb{C}^{n} &\to \mathbb{C} \\
>  \mid x \rangle &\mapsto \langle y \mid (\mid x \rangle) \tag{2}
> \end{array}$$

In $(2)$, these vectors are called *Bra*.

And then, roughly speaking, by Riesz Representation Theorem $[2]$, we can say that the inner product $\langle y \mid x \rangle$ is well defined as:

> $$\langle y \mid x \rangle =: \sum^{n}_{i=1} y^{*}_{i}x_{i} \tag{3}$$

Concerning the $(3)$, can we generalize to something like, $\langle y \mid x \rangle =: \sum^{n}_{i=1} g_{ij}y^{*i}x^{j}$ ? Where $g_{ij}$ is the metric tensor.

$$ * * * $$

$[1]$ NAKAHARA.M.; *Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Physical Realizations*, CRC Press, 2008.

$[2]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: I haven't had mathematical training quite at this level, but was under under the impression one can define the inner product in a variety of ways. Perhaps you could consider the fundamental properties of inner products and whether they apply to the inner product you propose (commutativity, distributivity, associativity, and positive definiteness).

Comment: You mean [PT stuff](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/70/6/R03)?